# How do I detect unfocus outside of a certain range?

Tags: javascript, css

**Solution:**

```
let focused = false;
document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focus", ()=>{
  document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="block";
})

document.getElementById('comment-id').addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>{
  $("#input-comment").focus();
  focused = true;
})

document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focusout", ()=>{
  if(!focused){
    document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="none";
  }
  else{
    focused = false;
  }

})
```

I have an `input` of text and when it gets focused a button bellow it appears.

Furthermore I want it to disappear when It is unfocused but still be able to click in the button that was bellow without it disappearing, which means I want to be able to click the button without the unfocus event getting triggered, but trigger it everywhere else.

Setting button to disappear after unfocused was my first try; after not being able to click it I decided to use a `timeout`, whcih looked like:

```
document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focusout", ()=>{
 setTimeout(()=>document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="none", 100);
})
```

The problem with this is that the input doesn't disappear instantly after unfocused when clicked on other elements.

Then I tried

```
let clicked = false;
document.body.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  document.getElementById('comment-id').addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="block";
    clicked = true;
  })
  setTimeout(()=>{
    if(!clicked){
      document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focusout", ()=>{
        document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="none";
      })
    }
  }, 500);
})
```

I was hoping it would block the onfocus event if I clicked the button first, but If I click the button the when unfocused it doesn't hide; if I clicked other elements, I won't be able to click the button.

**EDIT: Current code**

```
document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focus", ()=>{
  document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="block";
})

document.getElementById('comment-id').addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  $("#input-comment").focus();
})

document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focusout", ()=>{
  document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="none";
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button event handler, force focus on the input.

E.g:

```js
$("#button").on("click", () => {
 //code
 $("#input").focus();
});
```

And I suggest you add a listener for `onfocus` in your input so you can clean the `timeout`.

```js
document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("focusout", () => {
 hideButtonTimeout = setTimeout(()=>document.getElementById('comment-id').style.display="none", 100);
});

document.getElementById('input-comment').addEventListener("onfocus", () => {
 clearInterval(hideButtonTimeout);
});
```

Comment: I followed your code and edited my question with it because It still isn't working; when I click the button It still hides it; perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: You removed the timeout logic, try with this maybe?
Without timeout this will be triggered instantly, therefore it'll be hidden then. Using timeout you give some time for the code to executes and bring focus back to editor, which will trigger the event that will cleanInterval and avoid the element from being hidden